# Riemann's proof of his mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reviewing the proof of the Riemann mapping theorem, for which many books mention that Riemann's original proof is flawed because he didn't show the Dirichlet principle necessary for the existence of harmonic functions with prescribed boundary values. But my question is: Is this the *only* gap in his proof?

Let's assume a little regularity for $\partial \Omega$ (e.g., the exterior ball property.) Then the Dirichlet problem can be solved, even without using the Dirichlet principle (e.g., Perron's method.) However, we still have to check the map constructed this way is a bijection. I want to know whether there is an easy argument for that or it can be considered another gap of Riemann's proof.